# Generating import statements with scala macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I have the following code:

```
@mymacro @imports
val _1 = { import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer }

@mymacro
val _2 = { val yy: ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer.empty }
```

`@mymacro` is a scala macro that checks if it has been annotated with the `@imports`annotation. Part of the implementatation is as follows:

```
case (cc@q"${mods: Modifiers} val $tname: ${tpt: Tree} = ${expr: Tree}") :: Nil =>
      if (tname.toString().startsWith("_"))
        if (checkImports(mods, expr)) {
          q"import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer"
        }
        else
          q"{$expr}"
```

Currently the macro is able to transform the whole `val _1 = ...` statement to `import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer` (without the {} brackets!) But when the compilation continues, I keep getting the `not found: type ListBuffer` compilation error. Now I wonder if it is possible to fix this error somehow **without** having to define the import statement at the top of the file.

I am using the Scala 2.10 macro paradise plugin

Comment: In macros you generally have fully defined types. `val bufferTpe = tq"_root_.scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer"` and you use these all the time.

Comment: @flavian The `ListBuffer`is just an example. It should be possible to define multiple import statements inside the `_1` expression and use these inside the `_2`expression

Comment: Nope, the standard practice is to use non literal values just like I've shown you above. In a macro you always need to refer to a type by its FQDN starting with `_root_` to make sure no overrides can happen at the callsite of a macro when a user actually needs you macro.